# How to use Java Stream API to resolve sliding window problems?

Tags: java, algorithm, java-stream, sliding-window

Since Java 8, using Stream API has become prevalent. However, some problems can be easily resolved using batch based algorithm may not be easily resolved with stream based solution.

For example, given a stream of transactions of one credit card in timing sequence, I would like to find the card's total transaction amount in **each** 24 hours so that I can compare it with a threshold value to guess whether the card is stolen.
The stream data can be as simple as

```
transaction time            amount
2019-01-23T10:12:31.484Z    100
2019-01-24T00:12:30.004Z    50
2019-01-24T09:00:00.000Z    23
2019-01-27T05:10:00.300Z    65
```

This can be seen as a sliding window problem, which needs to check relations of elements. A batch based solution is not very complex. I can use a **queue** to keep only transactions happen in 24 hours.
the Algorithm can be roughly described with below steps:

1. create a queue and put the first transaction into the queue;
2. compare the next transaction with the transaction of queue head.
3. check the transaction time difference of the 2 transactions

   if the time difference is less than 24 hours,
4. add the transaction to the queue and return to step 2.

   else if it's longer than 24 hours, then

   5.1. calculate the total transaction amount of transactions in the queue as those transactions happen in 24 hours

   5.2 put the result into a result list.

   5.3 poll the queue to delete the oldest transactions until the new transaction happens less than 24 hours with a transaction in the queue.

   5.4 loop to step 2.

However, I find it difficult to implement the above algorithm using Java Stream API so I wonder is it a good idea to use Java stream to implement a sliding window problem? If yes, could anyone give some hint or some pseudo code using Java Stream to implement it? It's not necessary to use the above algorithm. Any stream based algorithm is ok.

Comment: Using streams shouldn't be a goal. It should be a means. If it solves your problem easily, readably and cleanly, use them. If not, don't use them.

Comment: thanks @RealSkeptic for your reply. but I don't know the reason I cannot come out a solution using stream is because stream is not suitable for this category of problems or is because I am not familiar with stream enough.

Comment: This can all be done directly in SQL. I don't see any reason to use Java code for this at all, whether with streams or without.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example how it can be done with `reduce`.
For collecting data class was created:

```java
class Row {

    private LocalDateTime date;
    private Integer value;

    public Row(LocalDateTime date, Integer value) {
        this.date = date;
        this.value = value;
    }

    // getters and setters
```

First read example data into stream.

```java
Stream<Row> readData = Stream.of(
        "2019-01-23T10:12:31    100",
        "2019-01-24T00:12:30    50",
        "2019-01-24T09:00:00    23",
        "2019-01-25T03:00:00    23",
        "2019-01-27T05:10:00    65")

        .map(s -> s.split("\\s+"))
        .map(a -> new Row(LocalDateTime.parse(a[0], DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME), Integer.valueOf(a[1])));
```

Than in `reduce` method collect every 24-hours period of rows to separated list and store it in main list.

```java
List<List<Row>> all = new ArrayList<>();
all.add(readData
        .map(Arrays::asList)
        .reduce(new ArrayList<>(), (a, v) -> {
            if (a.isEmpty()) {
                a.addAll(v);
            } else {
                LocalDateTime first = a.get(0).getDate().plusHours(24);
                if (first.isAfter(v.get(0).getDate())) {
                    a.addAll(v);
                } else {
                    all.add(a);

                    LocalDateTime last = v.get(0).getDate().minusHours(24);
                    a = new ArrayList<>(a.stream()
                            .filter(r -> last.isBefore(r.getDate()))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
                    a.addAll(v);

                }
            }
            return a;
        }));
```

At the end you can print out all list or calculate transactions values in each period.

```java
all.forEach(System.out::println);

all.stream().map(l -> l.stream()
        .map(Row::getValue)
        .reduce(Integer::sum)
        .get()
)
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

**UPDATE**

`reduce` can be also replace with simple `forEach`.
Then the main part would be like that and would be less complex:

```java
LinkedList<List<Row>> all = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(new ArrayList<>()));
readData
        .forEach(v -> {
            if (!all.getLast().isEmpty()) {
                // check if in 24h boundary
                LocalDateTime upperValue = all.getLast().get(0).getDate().plusHours(24);
                if (!upperValue.isAfter(v.getDate())) {
                    // create copy with row older earlier than 24h
                    LocalDateTime lowerValue = v.getDate().minusHours(24);
                    all.add(new ArrayList<>(all.getLast().stream()
                            .filter(r -> lowerValue.isBefore(r.getDate()))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList())));
                }
            }
            all.getLast().add(v);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" with doing this via Streams is that they are designed to be easily parallelizable. They are *not* sequential-only by design, and therefore purely sequential algorithms (as your queue-based algorithm is) do not work well with Streams. This is the leap to take from imperative to functional programming, you sometimes need a new algorithm, new approach. Translating imperative code into functional is not always straightforward.

If your data source can be easily [split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#spliterator()) multiple times (which, I think, is equivalent to being able to provide the required windows efficiently and concurrently), you can do this with Streams. For example, you could (re)use [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex)'s [`ofSublists()`](https://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#ofSubLists(java.util.List,int,int)) method if your data source is a `List`. This works because creation of any sublist is efficient and independent of the other sublists, so it can be safely called concurrently.

Alternatively, you can assume your Stream would never run parallelized, and use something focused on pure sequences, e.g. [jOOL](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL): [`Seq.sliding()`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.jooq/jool/latest/org/jooq/lambda/Seq.html#sliding-long-). This works on any Seq because the implementation can use iterative state without worrying about parallelism.